# epub3 using html + JS

Tags: javascript, html, epub, epub3

I was searching some ways to secure my content from being copied and I got epub3.

I'm developing a mobile app using Html5 + js + CSS, can I use epub3 zip file using js + html?
If yes how can I add epub reader in it.

my question may be wrong b/c I don't know much about it.

Need experts opinion on it.

Thanks

Comment: consider any hybrid mobile development platform like phonegap, titanium etc

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this will work, for several reasons:

1. epub is a file format for ebooks. Currently, only ebook reader apps can read this format. Embedding a reader into the file is no solution, because you need the reader app to read the file.
2. epub3, the newest version of the epub format, does include all those shiny gimmicks for interactivity like *JavaScript* et.al., and I think it also includes a lot of HTML5 features. But there is currently no reader app that supports all those features from epub3.
3. epub3 is still a zip archive, which can be opened by any application capable of reading the zip file format. If you want to secure your content, you can of course use the encryption mechanism of the zip format. But you need to either implement your own mechanism of decrypting the content when you want the user to have access to it, or you can use the existing schemes (Adobe DRM being the predominant one). In that case you need to sign on with Adobe and use their services for the encryption, which I suspect will be at a price.

Answer (score 1):

An open-source lighweight DRM for ePub3, called LCP, has been specified by IDPF, but we are still waiting for its implementation in the Readium SDK. Once done, you'll have your solution for free.

Answer (score 0):

If you make it readable, it cannot be also secured too from reading.
Furthermore DRMs are not very effective.
Streaming content is now the state of the art of content serving, and it is not immune to copying.

Is closing contents the key for your business?
Maybe you can reimaginate your business process in a more profitable way.

Answer (score -1):

Currently only Adobe supplies anything close to an industry-standard for encrypting epub files (see Adobe Content Server). It's very expensive, and proprietary. The epub spec does offer guidelines on how to use encryption, but it would require creating your own brand of DRM, which would then only work on your own reading system.

Epub 2 and 3 are web-friendly - they are usually HTML in a zip file. Epub 3 supports a subset of HTML 5 and some scripting capability. If you offered an online reading system, you could implement some sort of client-side decryption as the recently relaunched Mega upload service has done. It would be easily cracked, just so you know, unless you required the user to supply file-specific encryption keys that no one else knew.

Currently the best approach is to avoid DRM for epub files. Some publishers are imprinting the user's email address in the epub file as a deterrent to piracy, and others are putting files behind logins (access control). Both are better, IMHO, than paying Adobe's very high fees for the use of their proprietary content server.